# Почему картинка становится размытой при уменьшении, а текст нет?

Tags: html, css, изображения

```css
span {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

g {
  color: #4885ed;
}

o1, e {
  color: #db3236;
}

o2 {
  color: #f4c20d;
}

l {
  color: #3cba54;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://privacy.google.com/images/google-logo-lg.png" width="72" height="22">
<hr>
<span><g>G</g><o1>o</o1><o2>o</o2><g>g</g><l>l</l><e>e</e></span>
<hr>
<img src="https://privacy.google.com/images/google-logo-lg.png">
```

Comment: Потому что текст это вектор, а изображение растр.

Comment: А еще картинку надо пропорционально уменьшать, уберите width="72"

Answer (score 2):

Примените технику **[Отзывчивые изображения](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/images?hl=ru)**. Отзывчивый веб-дизайн предполагает, что в зависимости от параметров устройства могут меняться не только шаблоны страниц, но и контент. Указывая размеры изображения, применяйте относительные величины, чтобы оно не выходило за пределы области просмотра. Например, при параметре width: 50%; изображение в ширину будет занимать 50% вмещаемого элемента (а не области просмотра или актуального размера в пикселях). Например:

```
 img{max-width: 100%;}
```

Добавьте к элементу img атрибут **srcset**. Атрибут srcset расширяет функциональные возможности элемента img. Благодаря ему вам будет проще назначать изображения с учетом параметров устройства. Если браузер не поддерживает атрибут srcset, по умолчанию файл с изображением импортируется с помощью атрибута src. Вот почему так важно включать изображение 1x, которое может отображаться на любых устройствах, независимо от их свойств. Если браузер поддерживает атрибут srcset, вы можете определять список источников изображений и условий (через запятую) до поступления запроса. В результате загружаются и выводятся на экран только те изображения, которые соответствуют параметрам устройства. Вы можете определять размер обрабатываемого изображения, добавив дескриптор width. Это позволит браузеру автоматически вычислить оптимальную плотность пикселей и выбрать корректное изображение для загрузки. Например:

```
<img src=../images/zzz1399.jpg srcset="../images/zzz1300.jpg 1300w, ../images/zzz1000.jpg 1000w, ../images/zzz700.jpg 700w, ../images/zzz400.jpg 400w, ../images/zzz300.jpg 300w" width=1300 height=965 title="xxx" alt="xxx">
```

Если вы хотите, чтобы изображения менялись в зависимости от характеристик устройства (эффект *art direction*), воспользуйтесь элементом picture. Элемент picture задает декларативное решение для обеспечения нескольких версий одного изображения в зависимости от различных характеристик устройства: размера, разрешения, назначения и т. д. Используйте элемент picture, если у источника изображения несколько вариантов плотности пикселей, а также если в рамках отзывчивого веб-дизайна для некоторых типов экранов назначаются изображения с различающимися характеристиками. Например:

```html
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="head.jpg, head-2x.jpg 2x">
  <source media="(min-width: 450px)" srcset="head-small.jpg, head-small-2x.jpg 2x">
  <img src="head-fb.jpg" srcset="head-fb-2x.jpg 2x" alt="a head carved out of wood">
</picture>
```

Источник: **[статья Google Web Fundamentals "Отзывчивые изображения"](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/design-and-ui/responsive/images?hl=ru)**.

Answer (score 1):

Картинка в твоём случае растровая, а вот текст является векторным объектом. Вектор можно масштабировать бесконечно без потери качества, а по скольку твоя картинка растровая (состоит из пикселей), следовательно при некратном уменьшении некоторые пиксели смешиваются и появляется эффект размытия. Допустим ты уменьшишь картинку ровно в 4 раза, тогда картинка останется такой же чёткой