# Как добавить векторное изображение на сайт?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование

Как добавить векторное изображение на сайт?

Просто я скачал векторную иконку для сайта c [IconFinder](https://www.iconfinder.com/), но при уменьшении она все ровно размывается, как сделать так чтобы иконки стали четкими как текст?

**Пример:**

```html
<img src="https://codropspz-tympanus.netdna-ssl.com/codrops/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/TextFill_image5.png" height="20">
<b>TEXT</b>
```

Comment: используй svg, картинки всегда будут терять кач-во при уменьшении/увеличении

Comment: Возможно вам поможет этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/712522/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82/712673#712673

Answer (score 2):

.png это не векторный, а растровый формат. Скачайте иконку в .svg
Про различия можно почитать [тут](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/111-rastr-vector)